# How to add new element to the existing array field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi Below is my document

```
 "catid": [
           514500
          ],
 "studentid": 5282439,
```

In this catid field , I want to add new element 543 , where studentid = 5282439

I am trying the below query but it's giving me an exception

```
POST /parts/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
     "match": {
        "studentid": 5282439
     }
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.catid+= [543 ]"
}
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
"root_cause": [
   {
      "type": "class_cast_exception",
      "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script part is not correct, change it to this instead (i.e. move the script to the `script.inline` property):

```
POST /parts/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "studentid": 5282439
    }
  },
  "script" : {
     "inline": "ctx._source.catid += [543 ]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val , Thanks , but when I ran the above query m getting the following exception

Comment: "type": "class_cast_exception",
         "reason": "Cannot apply [+] operation to types [java.util.ArrayList] and [java.util.ArrayList]."

Comment: I'm using ES 5.2.2 Version

Comment: Remove the square brackets

Answer (score 5):

--> If the above answer doesn't work try this one

```
POST /parts/_update_by_query
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "studentid": 5282439
        }
      },
      "script" : {
          "lang":"painless",
         "inline": "ctx._source.catid.add(params.newsupp)",
         "params":{
             "newsupp":5302
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation as to ***why*** this is the answer.